# Still append / add params to url when using jquery ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, get, parameters

I am using jquery ajax get.

SO when my form is submitted it then submits to a php file but the url stays the same because i am using ajax.

```
$('#search').submit(function() {

$.get("http://example.co.uk/ajax/post.php", $(this).serialize(),
 function(response){

     $('#content').html(response.content);


   },"json");

 return false;
});
```

Ok this work url will stay the same. www.example.com

ok if i remove the return false so i get the default functionality of the form i get the following.

```
www.example.com?name=test&location=wales
```

ok here is what i am looking for i want to use ajax but still have the params appended to the title reason for this is i want my url to be shared with others so it will pull down the params from it.

example

```
www.example.com // will just so the basic page
```

but

```
www.example.com?name=test&location=wales // will show the page specific to wales
```

Any help please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’d probably need to use the hash (.com/#) in order for this to happen as you can’t just edit the URL.

Ben Alman’s [jQuery hashchange event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) is probably a good start. It allow you to detect when it changes.

This tutorial may also help: [Enabling the Back Button](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/enabling-the-back-button/) by [jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/).